# How I can guarantee that Android will create my files

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas

I wrote this code to save my canvas as bitmap but it didn't work. Can anyone help?

```
public void saveImage(){

    try {

        Bitmap bitmap = object.getDrawingCache();
        path = Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath();

        file = new File( path.toString() +"/image.png");
        FileOutputStream fos ;

        fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
        isFileCreated = file.exists();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't work"? Were any errors reported, or exceptions logged?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what you mean by "it didn't work", try creating the `File` differently. This is better than manually trying to build the path:

```
file = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory(), "image.png");
```